# Checkboxes with PHP & SQLExpress Server 2008

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, checkbox

I have a local application which currently reads data from a local SQL Server, this works well with SELECT queries and outputting text in a table however I'm having difficulty outputting a checkbox status either checked or unchecked :(

See my code:

```
<?php
    while( $row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt2, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input class=form-control id=input-readonly type=text name=supcode value=" . $row2['column1'] . " readonly></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=checkbox" . 
        if ($row2['checkbox_column1'] ==1) 
            echo "checked='checked'>" . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt2);
?>
```

The checkbox_column1 column is a BIT datatype

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You can start by putting attribute values in quotes. It is not strictly necessary, but this example illustrates why it is a good idea. When you have done that then you should take a look at the HTML output and make sure that it is correct. Using an [HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/) (which you should always use, especially when you are learning) would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry Sverri, the code above is just snippet..

Comment: Oh, and the PHP error will also cause problems. You cannot concatenate and `if` block.

Comment: Could you possibly correct my code to illustrate how I should show the if statement?

Comment: That way, the php code and html output would be correct - I would not like to fix the code in your question, and it is not an answer to the question: `while($row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt2, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) 
 {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><input class="form-control" id="input-readonly" type="text" name="supcode" value="' . $row2['column1'] . '" readonly /></td>';
        echo '<td><input type="checkbox"';
        if ($row2['checkbox_column1'] == 1) 
            echo ' checked="checked"';
  echo ' /></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }

    sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt2);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't closing the input if the checkbox column is empty. Also the concatation as noted won't work with the `if`.

Try updating to:

```
 $checked = $row2['checkbox_column1'] == 1 ? " checked='checked'" : '';  
 echo "<td><input type='checkbox'$checked></td>"; 
 echo "</tr>";
```

Demo: http://3v4l.org/HOojQ

If column == 1 output will be:

```
<td><input type='checkbox' checked='checked'></td></tr>
```

else

```
<td><input type='checkbox'></td></tr>
```

Comment: Great, please mark this as the accepted answer when you've tested thoroughly or post any questions/issues you encounter.